# WebGL rendering to floating-point-texture

Tags: floating-point, webgl, render-to-texture

I am writing some WebGL code and need to render to a floating point texture.
With the extensions `gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');` and  `gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear');` I am now able to create and draw this texture and use linear filter.
But it just does not seem to be calculated correctly.

Basically values need to get added together so I am using

```
    gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
    gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
    gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
    gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

when rendering to the texture. It can also occur that there are negative values to add.

Now after some hours of googling I came across this: [WEBGL_color_buffer_float extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_color_buffer_float/)

So far I was using the command

```
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, rttFramebuffer.width, rttFramebuffer.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
```

but I think I need to use `RGBA32F` instead. Could this be possible and if so, how can I use the extension format?

---

SOLVED: As the answer suggested, there were no errors with the used format. I assigned some wrong values to the shader uniforms and did use a very unfavourable background colour which lead to a wrong visualisation.

Comment: Hi, if you solved your problem, would you share our solution (the whole source code) as an example how to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float_linear');` does not give you floating point textures. It gives you the ability to use LINEAR filtering on floating point textures. `gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');` gives you the ability to create floating point textures.

As for this

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, rttFramebuffer.width, rttFramebuffer.height, 
              0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
```

It's correct. There is no RGBA32F in WebGL. It's inferred by `gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT`

Yes, it's stupid. That oversight was fixed in OpenGL ES 3.0 and will be fixed in WebGL 2.0 but in current WebGL that's the way you make a floating point texture.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just copied the wrong extension from my code. Thanks for the point on RGBA32F.  
Do you have any ideas why it would not draw the texture correctly? It appears like blending is not working when writing floats to the texture.

Comment: For WebGL2 I had to replace `OES_texture_float` by `EXT_color_buffer_float`  and then call `gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA32F, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null )`.